# Django Error in Django Setting File - TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple

Tags: python, django

I am using Django for a project.

I am getting this error --> TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple.

It indicates that line 17 in my setting.py file. The code in line 17 is as below.

```
14: import os
15: # Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
16: BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))),
17: TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: add setting.py TEMPLATES code

Comment: TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'

Comment: I see you haven't voted on any answers you've gotten yet. Up-voting answers you found helpful (by clicking on the up-arrow next to an answer), and accepting answers that solved your problem (by clicking the check-mark next to the answer) makes it easy for future users to see what the correct/best solution is. It also gives points to the people who take the time to answer (and signals to future helpers that they will also get points) -- in other words, it's a win-win-win situation ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If you try running this in the repl, you'll see that:

```
>>> BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()))),
>>> BASE_DIR
('c:\\srv',)
>>> isinstance(BASE_DIR, tuple)
True
>>> os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 84, in join
    result_path = result_path + '\\'
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
>>>
```

the problem is the `,` at the end of

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()))),  
                                                                         ^
                                                                         | this one
```

it works if you remove it:

```
>>> BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(os.getcwd())))
>>> os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
'c:\\srv\\templates'
```

in Python a comma is used to create tuples (even though many people think it's the parenthesis):

```
>>> 1,2,3
(1, 2, 3)
```

a two element tuple:

```
>>> 1,2
(1, 2)
```

and a one-element tuple:

```
>>> 1,
(1,)
```

Answer (score 0):

`TEMPLATE_DIR` is a list.
Change this line to

```
TEMPLATE_DIR = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
     'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates', 
     'DIRS': TEMPLATE_DIR, 
     'APP_DIRS': True,
     'OPTIONS': 
         {'context_processors': [
             'django.template.context_processors.debug',
             'django.template.context_processors.request',
             'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
             'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages', 
         ], 
         }, 
     }, 
]
```

Comment: I tried this before and now as well. Still getting the same error!

Comment: Hi Shafik, I removed the comma and issue solved even without making the TEMPLATE_DIR a directory. Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem and searched a  lot. But only this solved it finally. Plain and simple. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a front slash(/) instead of a comma(,)  in your "TEMPLATE's DIR:

like that: `'DIRS': [(BASE_DIR / 'templates')],`

Comment: 'DIRS': [(BASE_DIR / 'templates')],